# How can I calculate 2^n for large n?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that takes a number, `n`, as input, and outputs the result of 2 to the power of `n`. The problem is, `n` can be very large (up to 100,000). Essentially, I am trying to calculate `pow(2, n);` for very large numbers.

I think the way to do this is to store the digits in an array, since there is no built-in numeric type that can hold values that are this large.

The digits are in decimal format (base 10).

I am using C, not C++, so I cannot use STL vectors and other C++ containers. I also cannot use external libraries, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). I need to implement the algorithm manually in pure C.

Comment: Where is the least significant digit stored, in the first array entry (index 0) or the last one? It would be helpful to have an example with one input `n=...` and the expected resulting array.

Comment: @Socowi it doesn't really matter for me if the number is at the end or at the beginning of the array. I guess it would be easier to make the algorithm at the end. For example for n=9 the array should be 00000...000512

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't think so. At least a naive (and very slow) solution should be fairly easy to implement: Implement multiplication of two decimal numbers represented as digits of arrays, then use a loop to calculate 2*2*2*...*2. I think I start working on it right now :)

Comment: do you already have proprietary structure to store those numbers? Another method would be do deal only in terms of log to base 2 for all processing and just convert it /print it in the method which you already might have in your code.

Comment: @DarkAtom You probably need to apply some trick [like this one](https://headinside.blogspot.com/2014/10/calculate-powers-of-2-in-your-head.html). "*Start by breaking up the given power of 2 into the largest multiple of 10 which is equal to or less than the given power, and multiply it by whatever amount is leftover, which will be a number from 0 to 9.*"

Comment: I don't see any easy solution other than the dumb straight-forward "long" multiplication. Well, it can be optimized by recursively calculating and multiplying `2^(n/2)`, but still dumb.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you could be kind enough to share that method, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Clifford well I prefer to call it an array of unsigned chars for this purpose, because a string is usually used to store text. For the compiler though, they are the same exact thing.

Comment: The method of multiplication? The one we were taught in the school - multiply digit by digit, move the carry and such

Comment: Step 1: Write a function that multiplies 2 string decimal representation of a value.  Step 2 Use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method)

Comment: Make a "Big ass string table" where each value from 2^0 to 2^100,000 is represented as a string in a lookup.  Runs Constant time and requires no big num library.  Just a ton of RAM :)  Bonus points for generating the big ass table in another language that handles this well.

Comment: 100,000 entries isn't so bad?  It would be a list of pointers to string locations if needed.

Comment: @chux I might sound a little dumb here and I am sure it is easy to do, but can you give me a link for step 1?

Comment: My answer is a bit troll-y, but it solves the problem simply and requires nearly no C skill to implement.  The hardest part is making the table and that can be done any number of ways - even excel if needed.  You can even add commas if you want.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan ok, but where am I supposed to get the strings with the numbers from? Should I calculate 2^n 100k times on paper and use those results for the string table? Is that really what you are trying to say? EDIT: OK just now I saw your answer that it was troll.

Comment: Useful to know from the outset perhaps is that 2^n requires ceil(n * log10(2)) decimal digits (30103 for n-100000).

Comment: It's not a troll, but it feels trolly.  It answers the problem exactly, but it cannot really be expanded upon, so therefore it may not be the best engineering solution.  It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan This is a problem for homework though. If I get a good mark for that, it wouldn't be because I knew how to solve it, but for the effort put to complete that list of numbers :)))

Comment: For fun, I made an excel macro to make the numbers and it utterly fails after 2^50 or so :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not to compute 2 to a high power, but to convert this number to a decimal representation:

- Let's represent large numbers with arrays of unsigned 32-bit integers.
- Computing 2<sup>n</sup> is as easy as setting a single bit.
- Converting to binary can be performed by repeatedly dividing this number by 1000000000, producing 9 digits at a time.

Here is a simple but fast implementation:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_2_pow_n(int n) {
    int i, j, blen = n / 32 + 1, dlen = n / 29 + 1;
    uint32_t bin[blen], dec[dlen];
    uint64_t num;

    for (i = 0; i < blen; i++)
        bin[i] = 0;
    bin[n / 32] = (uint32_t)1 << (n % 32);

    for (j = 0; blen > 0; ) {
        for (num = 0, i = blen; i-- > 0;) {
            num = (num << 32) | bin[i];
            bin[i] = num / 1000000000;
            num = num % 1000000000;
        }
        dec[j++] = (uint32_t)num;
        while (blen > 0 && bin[blen - 1] == 0)
            blen--;
    }
    printf("2^%d = %u", n, dec[--j]);
    while (j-- > 0)
        printf("%09u", dec[j]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5)
        print_2_pow_n(i);
    print_2_pow_n(1000);
    print_2_pow_n(10000);
    print_2_pow_n(100000);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2^0 = 1
2^5 = 32
2^10 = 1024
2^15 = 32768
2^20 = 1048576
2^25 = 33554432
2^30 = 1073741824
2^35 = 34359738368
2^40 = 1099511627776
2^45 = 35184372088832
2^50 = 1125899906842624
2^55 = 36028797018963968
2^60 = 1152921504606846976
2^65 = 36893488147419103232
2^70 = 1180591620717411303424
2^75 = 37778931862957161709568
2^80 = 1208925819614629174706176
2^85 = 38685626227668133590597632
2^90 = 1237940039285380274899124224
2^95 = 39614081257132168796771975168
2^100 = 1267650600228229401496703205376
2^1000 = 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
2^10000 = 1995063116880758384883742<...>91511681774304792596709376
2^100000 = 9990020930143845079440327<...>97025155304734389883109376
```

2<sup>100000</sup> has 30103 digits, which is exactly `floor(100000 * log10(2))`. It executes in 33 milliseconds on my old laptop.

Comment: I like [your `while (j --> 0)` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)

Comment: @stef: the famous *dowto* operator is the best solution to iterate over the array with decreasing index values and it also works with unsigned types :)

Comment: @stef: I love this question, especially the picturesque [x slides to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909176/4593267)

Answer (score 3):

Simply make a bit array and set the nth-bit. Then divide by 10 as if the bit array were a little-endian 
number and print the remainders in reverse to get the base-10 representation of your nth-power of two.

This quick program below does it and it's giving me the same results as `bc`, so I guess it works.
The printing routine could use some tuning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

uint_least32_t div32(size_t N, uint_least32_t Z[/*N*/], uint_least32_t X[/*N*/], uint_least32_t Y)
{
    uint_least64_t carry; size_t i;
    for(carry=0, i = N-1; i!=-1; i--)
        carry = (carry << 32) + X[i], Z[i] = carry/Y, carry %= Y;
    return carry;
}

void pr10(uint_least32_t *X, size_t N)
{
    /*very quick and dirty; based on recursion*/
    uint_least32_t rem=0;
    if(!X[N?N-1:0]) return;
    rem = div32(N,X,X,10);
    while(N && !X[N-1]) N--;
    pr10(X,N);
    putchar(rem+'0');
}
int main(int C, char **V)
{
    uint_least32_t exp = atoi(V[1]);
    size_t nrcells = exp/32+1;
    uint_least32_t *pow  = calloc(sizeof(uint_least32_t),nrcells);
    if(!pow) return perror(0),1;
    else pow[exp/32] = UINT32_C(1)<<(exp%32);
    pr10(pow,nrcells);

}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./a.out 100
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

Comment: This works great for exp < 80'000, but for  exp >= 80'000 there is no output. Any idea why?

Comment: @Socowi Probably stack overflow due to recursion in the printing routine.

Comment: @Socowi I had an off by one error there. It should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

## Step 1: Decide how you're going to represent bignums

There exist libraries out there already for this. The [GNU Multiple Precision Integer library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) is a commonly used option. (But according to your edit, that isn't an option. You might still glance at some of them to see how they do things, but it isn't necessary.)

If you want to roll your own, I do *not* recommend storing the decimal digits. If you do that, you'll need to convert to and from a binary representation every time you want to do arithmetic on the components.  Better to have something like a linked list of `uint32_t`s, along with a sign bit.  You can convert from/to decimal when you want to read and write, but do your math in binary.

## Step 2: Implement exponentiation

I'll be assuming the linked list bignum implementation here; you can adapt the algorithms as needed.

If you're just calculating a power of 2, it's easy. It's a 1 followed by N 0s, so if each block stores M bits and you want to represent `2^N`, then just have `floor(N/M)` blocks of all 0s, and store `1 << (N % M)` in the most significant block.

If you want to be able to do exponentiation with *arbitrary* bases in an efficient manner, you should use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  The idea behind this is that if you want to compute 3^20, you don't multiply 3 * 3 * 3 * ... * 3.  Rather, you compute `3^2 = 3 * 3`.  Then `3^4 = 3^2 * 3^2.  3^8 = 3^4 * 3^4. 3^16 = 3^8 * 3^8`. And you store each of these intermediate results as you go.  Then once you reach the point where squaring it again would result in a larger number than the one you want, you stop squaring and assemble the final result from the pieces you have. In this case, `3^20 = 3^16 * 3^4`.

This approach computes the final result in 5 steps instead of 20, and since the time is logarithmic in terms of the exponent, the speed gain gets more pronounced the larger the exponent.  Even computing 3^100000 only takes 21 multiplications.

There isn't a clever approach to the multiplication that I know of; you can probably just do something along the lines of the basic long multiplication algorithm you learned in elementary school, but at the level of blocks: the reason we used `uint32_t`s earlier instead of uint64_t`s is so we can cast the operands to the larger type and multiply them without risk of losing the carry bits to overflow.

## Convert from binary to decimal for printing

First, find the largest multiple of 10 less than your number.
I leave doing this *efficiently* as an exercise for the reader, but you can probably manage it by doing exponentiation by squaring to find an upper bound, then subtracting various stored intermediate values to get down to the actual value faster than you would by dividing by 10 repeatedly.

Or you can just find the number by repeatedly multiplying by 10; the rest of this is going to be linear no matter how the first part is handled.

But however you get it, you have a `q` such that `q = k * 10, 10 * q > n, q <= n`, you can just cycle through one decimal digit at a time:

```
for (; q; q /= 10) {
   int digit = n / q; //truncated down to floor(n/q)
   printf("%d", digit);
   n -= digit * q;
}
```

It's possible that there's a more efficient method in the literature somewhere, but I'm not familiar with one offhand.  But it's not a major deal so long as we only need to do the inefficient part when writing output; that's slow no matter the algorithm. By which I mean, it might take a millisecond or two to print all 100,000 digits. That doesn't matter when we're displaying the number for human consumption, but if we had to wait a millisecond as part of a calculation in a loop somewhere, it'd add up and become terribly inefficient.  That's why we *never* store numbers in a decimal representation: by representing it as binary internally, we do the inefficient parts once on input and once on output, but everything in between is fast.

Comment: Even better than exponentiation by squaring would be fast fourier transformation.

Comment: This does not address the problem presented. There is no straight-forward way of representing the result in decimal form.

Comment: This would be really nice (especially for the powers of 2 method), but unfortunately the std library of C has no fast function of converting 1 followed by 100k zeroes from base 2 to base 10 and writing one is basically multiplying by 2 over and over again, which is well...doing the problem from the beginning.

Comment: Where is this in the answer?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd thought it beyond the scope of the question, but I've added a quick explanation of how to do it.

Comment: Ok, just so that I understand this correctly (about the last part): q is the biggest power of 10 smaller than the huge number and n is the number you get as input (0 <= n <= 100k)?

Comment: @DarkAtom `n` is the number you have represented in memory.  The full number, not just the exponent.  So let's say you had `2^11`: then `n = 2048`, and `q = 1000`.  The algorithm will print 2048 / 1000 (2), then subtract 2 * 1000, yielding 48.  Then it prints 48/100 (0), then 48/10 (4), then 8/1 (8).

Comment: @Ray but my number in memory is in binary stored in a linked list as you said, not in decimal form in a variable

Comment: @DarkAtom Variables do not store numbers in decimal form. `"2048"`, `"0x800"`, and `"1000 0000 0000"` are just different ways of *representing* the number `2048` as a string. When I say 2048, I mean the *number*, not any particular representation.  In the computer, the binary representation will be used.  In the comments here, I'm using the decimal version.

Comment: @Ray whatever the base the number is represented in, the variable would still not have the capacity to store the number. Do i need to do this algorithm on every block of the list? And if yes...how would it work? The list has the first block with the bits 1000... and the rest are all filled with 0s.

Comment: @DarkAtom Unfortunately, you can't do it on each block independently, since 10 doesn't divide evenly into 2. You'll need to implement a division function that works on the entire number. (And subtraction, but that one's fairly trivial.) That's the reason why we try to avoid storing things in decimal; converting between decimal and binary is a colossal pain, and all the operations on the CPU work in binary. Bignum libraries are something you need to build up piecemeal; once you have addition and subtraction, you can do multiplication and division. Once you have those, you can do exponentiation.

Comment: @DarkAtom You might be able to avoid writing an efficient general purpose division algorithm if you *just* need it for binary-to-decimal conversion. Since you know in advance that the value will always be between 0 and 9 inclusive, you can just do division by repeated subtraction without worrying that it'll take a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather naive and inefficient solution. As asked for, the numbers are represented in an array of decimal digits. We compute the exponential 2<sup>n</sup> by repeated addition of the number 2 with itself:
start with `e := 2` and repeat `e := e + e` n times.

To come up with an upper bound for the length of our `digits` array we use the following approach:

- The representation of number x in base b has ⌈log<sub>b</sub>(x)⌉ digits.
- Comparing the number of digits between the binary and decimal representation of any number x we find that they are only off by a constant factor if we neglect the rounding (⌈⌉).
  log<sub>2</sub>(x) / log<sub>10</sub>(x) = 1 / log<sub>10</sub>(2) = 3.3219... > 3
- 2<sup>n</sup> has log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>n</sup>) = n binary digits.
- Therefore 2<sup>n</sup> has around n / 3 decimal digits. Because of the rounding issues we add +1 to that.

```
void print(int digits[], int length) {
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        printf("%d", digits[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void times2(int digits[], int length) {
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int d = 2 * digits[i] + carry;
        digits[i] = d % 10;
        carry = d / 10;
    }
}
int lengthOfPow2(int exponent) {
    return exponent / 3 + 1;
}
// works only for epxonents > 0
void pow2(int digits[], int length, int exponent) {
    memset(digits, 0, sizeof(int) * length);
    digits[0] = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < exponent; ++i)
        times2(digits, length);
}
int main() {
    int n = 100000;
    int length = lengthOfPow2(n);
    int digits[length];
    pow2(digits, length, n);
    print(digits, length);
    return 0;
}
```

On unix-like systems you can check correctness for a fixed n using

```
diff \
  <(compiledProgram | sed 's/^0*//' | tr -d '\n') \
  <(bc <<< '2^100000' | tr -d '\n\\')
```

As already pointed out, this solution is not very efficient. Compiled with `clang -O2` computing 2<sup>100'000</sup> took 8 seconds on an Intel i5-4570 (3,2GHz).

The next step to speed this up would be to repeatedly cube your number instead of repeatedly multiplying by 2. Even with a naive implementation of the cube step this should be faster than the implementation presented in this answer.

If you need to be even more efficient you can implement the cube step using something like Karatsuba's algorithm or even fast fourier transformation (FFT). With the cubing approach and FFT you can compute 2<sup>n</sup> in around O(n·log(n)) (there may be an additional log(log(n)) factor due to rounding issues in FFT).

Answer (score 1):

<s>I wasn't able to find a solution in logarithmic complexity(exponentiation by squaring) but</s> I did manage to code a naive implementation with time complexity O(noOfDigits*pow), noOfDigits in 2^n will be n*log10(2)+1;

I only checked the answer with the first few digits of https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html and it seems to be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//MAX is no of digits in 2^1000000
#define MAX 30103
int a[MAX];
int n;
void ipow(int base, int exp,int maxdigits)
{
    a[0]=1;
    for (;exp>0;exp--){
            int b=0;
            for(int i=0;i<maxdigits;i++){
                a[i]*=base;
                a[i]+=b;
                b=a[i]/10;
                a[i]%=10;
            }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int base=2;
    int pow=100000;
    n=log10(2)*pow+1;
    printf("Digits=%d\n",n);
    ipow(base,pow,n);
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also wrote code for exponentiation by squaring but with an unoptimized multiplication function. Which seems to be faster than above implementation.

```
#define MAX 30103
int a[MAX];
int b[MAX];
int z[MAX];
//stores product in x[]; mul of large arrays implemented in n^2 complexity
//n and m are no of digits in x[] and y[]
//returns no of digits in product
int mul(int x[],int y[],int n,int m){
    for(int i=0;i<n+m;i++)
        z[i]=0;
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n+m;i++){
            z[i+j]+=x[i]*y[j];
            z[i+j]+=c;
            c=z[i+j]/10;
            z[i+j]%=10;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n+m;i++){
            x[i]=z[i];
    }
    if(x[n+m-1]==0)
        return n+m-1;
    return n+m;
}
//stores answer in x[]
int ipow(int base, int exp)
{
    int n=1,m=0;
    for(int i=0;base>0;i++){
        b[i]=base%10;
        base/=10;
        m++;
    }
    a[0]=1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            n=mul(a,b,n,m);
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            break;
        m=mul(b,b,m,m);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int base=2;
    int pow=100000;
    n=log10(2)*pow+1;
    printf("Digits=%d\n",n);
    ipow(base,pow);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice contribution.  Also done complex enough that if the student turns it in without understanding it, they will get a big 0.

Comment: 26 seconds of execution time to calculate 2^100000.

Comment: Yeah, take the results and output into a string table and then use that.  Instant run time :)

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri Your comment on the the measured time may be a bit misleading. Yes, compiled with just `clang -lm` I get 30 seconds too, but with `clang -O2` it's just 7 seconds. By the way, I compared the result for pow=100'000 automatically and all digits are correct.

Comment: Just realized Java BigInteger can do the same operation within 1 second.

Comment: With gcc -O2 now my updated code gets executed in 3 seconds. I didn't know about these compiler parameters until now.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original problem statement does not specify the output base, here is a joke implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_2_pow_n(int n) {
    printf("2^%d = 0x%d%.*d\n", n, 1 << (n % 4), n / 4, 0);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        print_2_pow_n(i);
    print_2_pow_n(100);
    print_2_pow_n(100000);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2^0 = 0x1
2^1 = 0x2
2^2 = 0x4
2^3 = 0x8
2^4 = 0x10
2^5 = 0x20
2^6 = 0x40
2^7 = 0x80
2^8 = 0x100
2^9 = 0x200
2^10 = 0x400
2^11 = 0x800
2^12 = 0x1000
2^13 = 0x2000
2^14 = 0x4000
2^15 = 0x8000
2^100 = 0x10000000000000000000000000
2^100000 = 0x10...<0 repeated 24998 times>...0
```

Comment: Powers of two power of two base. That's cheating! :D

Comment: O(n) solution, so UV.  Note: 100,000 may exceed `*printf()`  _environmental limit_, (c18 § 7.21.6.1 15) which is at least 4095 - thus "breaking" `printf()`.

Comment: @chux: indeed it is a stress test for `printf`'s quality of implementation. It works as expected on OS/X with Apple BSD based Libc and also on linux with the GNU libc. Other systems might be less sturdy :)