# How can I calculate 2^n+2^n-1+...+2^k mod 2^60 in C++, where the value of 2^i can be very big?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, exponent, exponentiation

For a programming question I have to print the expression `2^n+2^n-1+...+2^k mod 2^60`, where `1<=k<n<=240`?

Basically, how can I calculate 2^240 mod 2^60? If this can be solved, I can make it work for n<240 as well!

I read an answer here:
[How can I calculate 2^n for large n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385984/how-can-i-calculate-2n-for-large-n)

But, that calculates for large values of `n` and not `2^n`.

Any help?

Comment: `2^240 mod 2^60` = 0

Comment: Does this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation help you? Basically: 1. You can do each summand separately anyway, 2. (a*b) mod m = (a mod m)*(b mod m) mod m

Comment: @Aziuth I don't think that's very useful in this context

Comment: 2^n is just 1 followed by n zeroes. You could do it as a string.

Comment: All the powers > 60 come out to 0 mod 2^60, so you can just ignore them.  The other ones can be calculated with a left shift in a 64-bit int. Easy.  Probably what you're asking for is not really what you want.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans So, any power of 2 greater than 2^60 when mod by 2^60 comes out zero because it is totally divisible, right? Also, How to do that 64bit int thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
2^k + 2^k+1 + ... + 2^n-1 + 2^n mod 2^60
```

=

```
2^k * (2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^n-k-1 + 2^n-k) mod 2^60
```

=

```
2^k * ((2^n-k+1)-1) mod 2^60
```

=

```
(2^n+1 - 2^k) mod 2^60
```

=

```
(2^n+1 mod 2^60 - 2^k mod 2^60) mod 2^60
```

- k >= 60: result is 0 because both 2^n+1 and 2^k can be divided by 2^60
- k < 60:

  - n >= 59: result is -2^k
  - n < 59: result is 2^n+1 - 2^k

Because of the conditions, all those numbers can be calculated because fit properly on a long variable (64 bits).